# How to append float to a python list?

Tags: python, list

I'm struggling to append float value into python list. It tells me `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`. Values that I'm trying to pass are for example ->  0.08
this is part of my code:

```
final_list=[]
...

data = json.loads(r.text)
try:
    myId = data['requestGeneralDetails']['workTimeToClose']
except KeyError:
    print ('Someone is still working on this request')
for each_requ in myId:
    final_list.append(each_requ)
return final_list
```

Could someone help with this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myId is a **float** so directly append it in the list using

```
final_list.append(myId)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is about iterating over the float value which is not possible because your myId is already a float. Try appending it as it is.